# How can I parse Web API JSON response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

I created an ASP.NET Web API but I can't deserialize it's responses in Android studio. And the response is like this lines:

```
[{
  "FName": "name",
  "LName": "family",
  "Mobile": "",
}]
```

Also! in this file each separated class has no title (In other files for each class a title is available).

This is my code which I used to replace JSON as XML for response type (project manager/app_start/webconfig.cs):

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Comment: is this response in C# or javascript?

Comment: This is reply from asp web api server

Comment: The media-type for JSON is application/json, not text/html. Also in JSON there is no concept of "title" in the way you've used it. What your JSON shows is a collection (the []) of objects, each with those 3 properties. If you were to create a type in your client matching that and do something like `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ThatType>>(jsonText);`, it should give you what you're after.